# Is there a way to enable keystroke input for a specific fulfillment while being on the call?

Tags: dialogflow-cx

I am building an agent and integrated it with telephony. I don't want the caller to orally say some of the sensitive or complex information to the agent, instead I want the caller to key in the information using the keypad while being on the call with the agent.

Answer (score 1):

To allow the caller to enter digits via the phone keypad, you can [enable and configure DTMF (Dual-tone multi-frequency signaling) for parameters](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/parameter#dtmf).